# Eigenvalues of a certain structured matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Let $a, b$ and $c$ be three distinct positive integers. Consider the following $2k\times  2k$ matrix:
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&\cdots&b&c&c&\cdots&c\\
b&a&\cdots&b&c&c&\cdots&c\\
\vdots&&&\vdots&\vdots&&&\vdots\\
b&\cdots&b&a&c&c&\cdots&c\\
c&c&\cdots&c&a&b&\cdots&b\\
c&c&\cdots&c&b&a&\cdots&b\\
\vdots&&&\vdots&\vdots&&&\vdots\\
c&c&\cdots&c&b&b&\cdots&a
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where every diagonal entry equals $a$, every entry in the top right and bottom left $k\times k$ block equals $c$, and the remaining entries are $b$.

It can be checked that two of the eigenvalues of $A$ are $a+(k-1)b+kc$ and $a+(k-1)b-kc$, with eigenvectors $[1,\cdots,1]$ and $[1,\cdots,1,-1,\cdots,-1]$, respectively. Since this is a full rank matrix, it will have $2k$ nonzero eigenvalues. What can be said about the remaining eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u,v\in\mathbb R^k$ be any pair of vectors orthogonal to $(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. Then
$$
A\pmatrix{u\\ v}=(a-b)\pmatrix{u\\ v}.
$$
Those $u$s span a $(k-1)$-dimensional subspace and similarly for those $v$s. Therefore $a-b$ is an eigenvalue of geometric multiplicity $2(k-1)$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!